# PHP array_merge order one value per array

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I'd like two merge two array with a custom order: take one value from array one and then one from array two as following:

```
$array1 = array('key1' => 'value_1_1', 'key2' => 'value_1_2');
$array2 = array('key1' => 'value_2_1', 'key2' => 'value_2_2');

//merge array with custom order

$array_result = array('key1' => array('value_1_1', 'value_2_1'),
                      'key2' => array('value_2_1', 'value_2_2')
                     )
```

Values are different, keys same on both arrays.

Comment: You'd have to rename the keys because you can't have duplicate key values.

Comment: The solution could be create multi dim arrays, but the key has to be the same

Comment: This should be the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512889/php-grouping-array-values-by-keys/21512967#21512967

Comment: No, keys are actually strings not int

Comment: What shall happen to keys only present in one array?

Answer (score 2):

Built-in function

```
$result = array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();
foreach(array_keys($array1 + $array2) as $key)
{
    if(array_key_exists($key, $array1) && array_key_exists($key, $array2))
        $result[$key] = array($array1[$key], $array2[$key]);
    else
        $result[$key] = array_key_exists($key, $array1) ? $array1[$key] : $array2[$key];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
$array1 = array('key1' => 'value_1_1', 'key2' => 'value_1_2');
$array2 = array('key1' => 'value_2_1', 'key2' => 'value_2_2');
$result = array();

/* Create index for $result */
foreach($array1 as $data => $value) {
    $result[$data] = array();
}

/* Craete Value for $result from array 1*/
foreach($array1 as $data => $value) {
    array_push($result[$data], $value); 
}

/* Craete Value for $result from array 2*/
foreach($array2 as $data => $value) {
    array_push($result[$data], $value);
}
```